# RxSwift how to append to BehaviorSubject<[]>

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Since Variable is deprecated in RxSwift 4, what is the equivalent way for `BehaviorSubject` to do the following?

```
let observable = Variable<[Int]>([])
observable.value.append(1)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*BehaviorRelay* is a replacement for *Variable* in newer versions  *RxSwift*, which seem to work similarly. *Variable* has a property *value* which emits event when changed. Similar to that with BehaviorRelay, you can use underlying *accept(:)*, method to change the value.

```
let array = BehaviorRelay(value: [1, 2, 3])

array.subscribe(onNext: { value in
    print(value)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)


// for changing the value, simply get current value and append new value to it
array.accept(array.value + [4])
```

Nevertheless, this can be worked on with *BeviourSubject* as well if you wish to,

```
let subject = BehaviorSubject(value: [10, 20])
subject.asObserver().subscribe(onNext: { value in
    print(value)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You can get latest value from *BehaviorSubject* with a throwing function *value()*, and so appending the value with look like this,

```
do {
    try subject.onNext(subject.value() + [40]) // concatenating older value with new 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Notice that you would need to call onNext to pass new value to *BehaviorSubject* which is not as simple as it is with *Variable* or *BahaviorRelay*

Answer (score 10):

We can also use `BehaviorRelay` extension to append objects easily:

```
extension BehaviorRelay where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {

    func add(element: Element.Element) {
        var array = self.value
        array.append(element)
        self.accept(array)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
self.wishList.add(element: item.element)
```

wishList is object of `BehaviorRelay`